# I Keep Having a Syntax Error Message With This Python Code

Tags: python, syntax-error

Having issue with small python script. trying to add 1 to a global variable every 3 iterations. I keep seeing

"for 3 in scalerVal:
        ^
SyntaxError: cannot assign to literal"

I will appreciate an answer

```
    x1 = 0
    x2 = 0
    x3 = 0
    x4 = 0
    x5 = 0
    x6 = 0
    x7 = 0
    x8 = 0
    x9 = 0

    itVal = 0


    scalerVal = 3

    # -- STEP 1: --
    # (greatest value) = 3 * itVal + itVal
    # adder = (greatest value) - (current value) = (differnce in value) + itVal
    # scaler = itVal - intVal - itVal

    # -- STEP 2: --
    # add the adder to all n values

    def a1():

      global x1
      x1 = x1 + 3
      global x2
      x2 = x2 + 2
      global x3
      x3 = x3 + 1
      global x4
      x4 = x4 + 2
      global x5
      x5 = x5 + 2
      global x6
      x6 = x6 + 1
      global x7
      x7 = x7 + 1
      global x8
      x8 = x8 + 1
      global x9
      x9 = x9 + 1

      global scalerVal
      for 3 in scalerVal:
        scalerVal + 1
        return()

      global itVal
      if itVal == 0:
        #gVal = 3 * itVal + itVal
        #adder = gVal - x1 + itVal
        #x1 = x1 + adder
        itVal = itVal + 1
        print(x1, x2, x3, x4, x5, x6, x7, x8, x9, itVal)
        return()

      else:
        gVal = scalerVal * itVal + itVal
        adder = gVal - x1 + itVal
        x1 = x1 + adder
        itVal = itVal + 1
        print(x1 , x2, x3, x4, x5, x6, x7, x8, x9, itVal)
        return()

      return()

    def a2():

      global x1
      x1 = x1 + 2
      global x2
      x2 = x2 + 3
      global x3
      x3 = x3 + 2
      global x4
      x4 = x4 + 2
      global x5
      x5 = x5 + 2
      global x6
      x6 = x6 + 2
      global x7
      x7 = x7 + 1
      global x8
      x8 = x8 + 1
      global x9
      x9 = x9 + 1

      global itVal

      return()

    def a3():

      global x1
      x1 = x1 + 1
      global x2
      x2 = x2 + 2
      global x3
      x3 = x3 + 3
      global x4
      x4 = x4 + 1
      global x5
      x5 = x5 + 2
      global x6
      x6 = x6 + 2
      global x7
      x7 = x7 + 1
      global x8
      x8 = x8 + 1
      global x9
      x9 = x9 + 1

      global itVal
      if itVal == 0:
        #gVal = 3 * itVal + itVal
        #adder = gVal - x3 + itVal
        #x3 = x3 + adder
        itVal = itVal + 1
        print(x1, x2, x3, x4, x5, x6, x7, x8, x9, itVal)
        return()

      else:
        gVal = 3 * itVal + itVal
        adder = gVal - x3 + itVal
        x3 = x3 + adder
        itVal = itVal + 1
        print(x1 , x2, x3, x4, x5, x6, x7, x8, x9, itVal)
        return()

      return()



    def valAdd():

      #for _ in range(1000000000):
        #a1()

      a1()
      a2()
      a3()



      print(x1, x2, x3, x4, x5, x6, x7, x8, x9, itVal)

      return()

    valAdd()
```

Having issue with small python script. trying to add 1 to a global variable every 3 iterations. I keep seeing

"for 3 in scalerVal: ^ SyntaxError: cannot assign to literal"

I will appreciate an answer

Comment: What do you expect `for 3 in scalerVal:` to do?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are using a constant where you should put a variable instead.

More specifically, in the python for loop, it should be something like this:

```
for x in [scalerVal]
```

Actually, the first one should be a variable and the second one should be a iterable

Answer (score 0):

3 needs to be a variable name such as X

```
for x in scalerVal:
  x + 1
  return()
```

Also, scalarVal should be a list or array, not a scalar for use with for.

You can just use the value directly.

Comment: Strictly speaking, it just has to be an lvalue; `for x[3] in scalerVal:` would be syntactically valid, as long as `x` is something for which `x[3] = ...` makes sense.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. but after plugging it in. I am getting TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable

Comment: As mentioned earlier scalarValue is not iterable and therefore can't be used on the right side of for expression.  If you want to count up to scalarValue in a for loop use:
      for x in range(0..scalarValue):

It is hard to give the right answer without knowing what you are trying to do though.